# How can I match a whole word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to search a single whole word through a textbox. Say I search "me", I should find all occurrences of the word "me" in the text, but not "memmm" per say.

I am using JavaScript's `search('my regex expression')` to perform the current search (with no success).

After several proposals to use the `\b` switches (which don't seem to work) I am posting a revised explanation of my problem:

For some reason this doesn't seem to do the trick. Assume the following JavaScript search text:

```
var lookup = '\n\n\n\n\n\n2    PC Games        \n\n\n\n';
lookup  = lookup.trim() ;
alert(lookup );

var tttt = 'tttt';
alert((/\b(lookup)\b/g).test(2));
```

Moving lines is essential

Comment: your code is looking for "lookup" in the string "2".

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To use a dynamic regular expression see my updated code:

```
new RegExp("\\b" + lookup + "\\b").test(textbox.value)
```

Your specific example is backwards:

```
alert((/\b(2)\b/g).test(lookup));
```

[Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)

[Regex Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: `var str = "pc+pc2/pc2+pc2*rr+pd";`
`var res = str.match(new RegExp("([\\W])pc2([\\W])",'g'));`
I want `+pc2/`, `+pc2*` and `/pc2+`.

Comment: Have an any idea @ChaosPandion.

Comment: I want to check before and after special character exists or not. Problem is in first match `/` is remove. So after that it is start to check from `pc2+pc2*rr+pd`. And I not get `/pc2+`.

Comment: *Note*: `\b` word boundaries in javascript only supports ASCII characters.

Answer (score 30):

Use the word boundary assertion `\b`:

```
/\bme\b/
```

Answer (score 10):

You may use the following code:

```
var stringTosearch ="test ,string, test"; //true
var stringTosearch ="test string test"; //true
var stringTosearch ="test stringtest"; //false
var stringTosearch ="teststring test"; //false

if (new RegExp("\\b"+"string"+"\\b").test(stringTosearch)) {
  console.log('string found');
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var lookup = '\n\n\n\n\n\n2    PC Games        \n\n\n\n';
lookup  = lookup.trim() ;
alert(lookup );
                var tttt = 'tttt';
                alert((/\b(lookup)\b/g).test(2));

</script>
```

It's a bit hard to tell what you're trying to do here. What is the `tttt` variable supposed to do?

Which string are you trying to search in? Are you trying to look for `2` within the string `lookup`? Then you would want:

```
/\b2\b/.test(lookup)
```

The following, from your regular expression, constructs a regular expression that consists of a word boundary, followed by the string `"lookup"` (not the value contained in the variable `lookup`), followed by a word boundary. It then tries to match this regular expression against the string `"2"`, obtained by converting the number `2` to a string:

```
(/\b(lookup)\b/g).test(2)
```

For instance, the following returns `true`:

```
(/\b(lookup)\b/g).test("something to lookup somewhere")
```