# How can I detect a html class with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I use these three lines of code to detect lesser internet explorer versions.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="lt-ie8 lt-ie7 lesser-browser get-lost-ie-user please-leave-now"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="lt-ie8 ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html class="gtie7"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Using javascript, how can I find out whether or not the lt-ie8 class is enabled for the `<html>` element?

Comment: No demonstrated research effort, and it's not useful because it's using browser detection which is almost never the right way of solving issues with missing features.

Comment: @KevinB i actually am using this to block ie6 and ie7, because anyone still using them... well I am not going to say. I would get arrested if I did

Comment: @KevinB I still need to warn users about their ungodly habits, so that they might upgrade and then re-visit with their firefox 27 super browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JavaScript, you can use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].classList.contains("lt-ie8");
```

That gives the list of classes. If `classList` is not implemented, it can be checked this way:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className.indexOf("lt-ie8") != -1)
  // The browser...
```

Or use jQuery's [**`$.hasClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) if there's a class set:

```
$("html").hasClass("lt-ie8");
```

So, you can use it this way:

```
if ($("html").hasClass("lt-ie8"))
  // Class is enabled.
else
  // Class is not there.
```

Comment: jquery isn't needed for everything

Comment: @mortaga That funny question was tagged under jQuery! FYI!!! Check [Revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19687783/revisions). And I have provided the JavaScript version too!

Comment: and browser detection is almost never needed. and yet people still do it.

Comment: my apologies, haven't see the jquery tag.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `document.body.parentNode` to get your `<html>` tag as the DOM does not need to be searched like the other methods. Reimplementing the jQuery `hasClass` method is the best way to check if a javascript class has a class in legacy browsers since the other methods normally don't work when there are multiple classes or if the class is a substring of another class.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10960588/1156119)

```
function hasClass(elem, klass) {
    return (" " + elem.className + " ").indexOf(" " + klass + " ") > -1;
}

if (hasClass(document.body.parentNode, "lt-ie8")) {
    // ...
}
```

If you're only targeting modern browsers then using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) is the best option.

```
if (document.body.parentNode.classList.contains("lt-ie8")) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('lt-ie8').length > 0) {
    // EDIT due to the important comment below
    //console.log("you are using a crappy browser");
    alert("you are using a crappy browser");
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that break the page, since said crappy browser doesn't support console.log() if the console isn't open?

Comment: `console || (console = { 'log' : function(m) { alert(m) } })` :D

Comment: why downvotes since this answer perfectly the question, and was the first one.

Comment: Not quite first, but still see no reason for dv

Answer (score 0):

```
var isBrowserCrappy = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className.indexOf('lt-ie8') !== -1;
```

Comment: @KevinB - yeah, realized that a sec ago. Thx for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if( document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className == 'gtie7' )
    alert( 'html has class "gtie7"' );
```

Comment: won't work since the html element can also have other classes (in the example at least)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got the question tagged with `jquery` just use:

```
if ($(".lt-ie8").length > 0) {
    . . . do stuff . . .
}
```

I tested it in Firefox, IE7, IE9, and Chrome . . . works fine in all of them . . .

**Edit:** `$("html.lt-ie8").length` is even more efficient . . .

**Note:** in HTML4 and XHTML, `class` is not a valid attribute for the `<html>` tag.  Even though it seems to work, you might want to consider moving it to the `<body>` tag instead.