# JavaScript - check if a given substring is surrounded by letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, string

**TL;DR**

How do I return strings that contain a substring, but only if **is not** surrounded by letters?

**CONTEXT**

I'm creating a translation tool to a fictional language. I have a lexicon stored in a JSON object and am using the following code to translate each word from the input to another word for the output:

```
    //loop through lexicon and if inputted word is in values, return corresponding key -> NEED A WAY TO GET 
    for(var word in inputArray){    
        for(var key in lexicon){
            var value = lexicon[key];
            var term = inputArray[word];

            // check if the term appears as a value in the selected lexicon
            if(value.indexOf(term) !== -1){
                // if key contains commas, then take only what's before the first comma
                if(key.indexOf(',') !== -1){
                    match = key.substring(0, key.indexOf(','));
                // if there are no commas, return the whole key
                } else{
                    match = key;
                }
                outputArray.push(match)
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM**

Although this method works for longer words, shorter words such as "**hi**" will be matched to the first value found in the lexicon, which could be another word, such as "t**hi**ng". Since some of the object values contain comma-separated words, I need a way to pull only words which are NOT surrounded by letters.

**DESIRED RESULT**

The translation of "**thing**" will not be returned if I type "**hi**", but the translation of "**hi,hello,goodday**" or "**hello,hi**" will be returned.

Comment: Use `\b` - word boundaries - in a regex pattern. If you just search for whole words, it is enough. Your desired result is unclear: there is no `hi` in `hello`.

Comment: sounds like you want `if(match.endsWith(key)){ ...` (after the left-side-of-comma chop)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - sorry if it was unclear, but the keys/values contain more than one word. The translation (i.e. value) of the "hello,hi" key would be returned because it is a single key composed of two words separated by a comma. I hope that makes more sense!

Comment: Could you provide an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I just need to know which variable contains what text.

Comment: Just got it to work while creating an MVCE for you :) - thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated! I ended up using the solution below to define the term to search for as a RegEx (`var term = new RegExp("\\b" + inputArray[word] + "\\b")`), and then my if statement is `if(term.test(value)){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to match the whole word in a string? You may use regular expressions for this purpose:

```
new RegExp("\\b" + lookup + "\\b").test(text)
```

See here for more details:
[whole word match in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232934/whole-word-match-in-javascript)

Comment: If you need to use `RegExp#test()`, you cannot declare the regex with `/g` modifier. You should replace `new RegExp("\\b" + lookup + "\\b", "g").test(text)` with `new RegExp("\\b" + lookup + "\\b").test(text)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I tried using `var term = new RegE@xp("\\b" + inputArray[word] + "\\b")` and then still the same `if(value.indexOf(term) !== -1){` as above, but that does not seem to work - any ideas?

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect the comments