# How to not return words with the same root in a JavaScript regular expression matching?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to loop over a list of words and match them against a regex and I'm getting too many matches (looking for ALPHA also matches ALPHABET for example). Here is my script:

```
function evaluateChunk(my_chunk, my_input) {
  var rows = my_chunk.split(LINE_BREAKS).filter(Boolean),
    word_string = my_input.replace(/ /g, "|"),
    re = new RegExp("(" + word_string + ")(?:\\([0-9]\\))?"),
    output_dict = {"error_list": [], "match_dict": {}},
    row_len = rows.length,
    candidate,
    j;

  for (j = 0; j < row_len; j += 1) {
    candidate = rows[j].split(" ")[0];
    if (candidate.match(re) !== null) {
      output_dict.match_dict[candidate] = rows[j].split("]").pop().trim();
    }
  }
  output_dict.error_list = word_string.split("|").reduce(function (arr, word) {
    if (output_dict.match_dict[word] === undefined) {
      arr.push(word);
    }
    return arr;
  }, []);

  return output_dict;
}
```

my_input will be something like `ALPHA BETA`, which will be converted to `ALPHA|BETA` and put into the regular expression (which needs to catch both `ALPHA` AND `ALPHA(2)` hence the regex). Rows is a chunk from a dictionary I'm trying to look inputs up from.

My issue is that the regular expressions should:

```
ALPHA    => match (ok)
ALPHA(2) => match (ok)
ALPHABET => no match (doesn't work, is also returned)
ALPHANUMERIC => no match (doesn't work, is also returned)
```

Question:
How do I make a regular expression non greedy to only return exact word matches and no words with the same ... root?

Comment: Try `re = new RegExp("\\b(" + word_string + ")\\b(?:\\([0-9]\\))?")`. If you need to match the whole string, try `re = new RegExp("^(" + word_string + ")(?:\\([0-9]\\))?$")`

Comment: cool. worked. Want to make it answer so I can check? Thanks you very much.

Comment: Word boundaries worked? Or anchors? Anyway, the question is a dupe.

Comment: ah, I did not see your edit. your first solution with the word boundaries worked. If it's a dupe, please vote to close, but I've stumbled over the same issue a few times and never managed to find a good answer on SO.

Comment: Or [whole word match in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232934/whole-word-match-in-javascript). As I say, it is still a duplicate. Thee are a lot of questions on how to match a whole word/string on SO. Search for a "word boundary regex" on Google.

Comment: I see. Thanks for chipping in.