# Searching for words in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a function that finds the string that contains all words from an array.

I have tried this:

```
function multiSearchOr(text, searchWords){
    var searchExp = new RegExp(searchWords.join("|"),"gi");
    return (searchExp.test(text))?"Found!":"Not found!";
}

alert(multiSearchOr("Hello my name sam", ["Hello", "is"]))
```

But this only alert "Found" when one of the words have been found.

I need it to alert me when all the words are in the string.

An example:

```
var sentence = "I love cake"    
var words = ["I", "cake"];
```

I want the application to alert me when it finds all of the words from the array in the string sentence. Not when it only found one of the words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [whole word match in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232934/whole-word-match-in-javascript)

Comment: @MatthewSanetra I dont need the whole world, i need it to alert me when all of the words from array has been found in the string.

Comment: You need to iterate over array, create regex, `test` it and if not found `return false;` else `return true;`.

Comment: Count Total Amount Of Specific Word In a String JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/a/65036248/4752258

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're interested in using only a single regular expression, then you need to use a positive lookahead when constructing your expression. It will look something like that:

```
'(?=\\b' + word + '\\b)'
```

Given this construction, you can then create your regular expression and test for the match:

```
function multiSearchOr(text, searchWords){
    var regex = searchWords
        .map(word => "(?=.*\\b" + word + "\\b)")
        .join('');
    var searchExp = new RegExp(regex, "gi");
    return (searchExp.test(text))? "Found!" : "Not found!";
}
```

Comment: You can safely remove `g` flag.

Comment: Count Total Amount Of Specific Word In a String JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/a/65036248/4752258

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example. You simply need to iterate over the array and compare if the words are present in the string or not using `indexOf()`. if it is not equal then alert Not found otherwise alert Found.

```js
function multiSearchOr(text, searchWords){

   for(var i=0; i<searchWords.length; i++)
   {
    if(text.indexOf(searchWords[i]) == -1)
      return('Not Found!');
   }
   return('Found!');
}

alert(multiSearchOr("Hello my name sam", ["Hello", "is"]));
```

Comment: This is case-sensitive. OP wants to check case-**in**sensitively.

Comment: @Tushar Add `.toLowerCase()` to the variables being passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for ? In this way, you can use more complex sentences that contain non-alphanumeric characters.

```js
var sentence = "Hello, how are you ?"
var test1 = ["Hello", "how", "test"];
var test2 = ["hello", "How"];

function multiSearchOr(text, searchWords){
  if (text && searchWords) {
      var filteredText = text.match(/[^_\W]+/g);
      
      if (filteredText !== null) {
        var lowerCaseText = filteredText.map(function(word) { 
          return word.toLowerCase(); 
        });
        
        for (var i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++) {
          if (lowerCaseText.indexOf(searchWords[i].toLowerCase()) === -1) {
            return "Not found!";
          }
        }
        
        return "Found!"
      }
    
      return "Error: the text provided doesn't contain any words!"
  }
  
  return "Error: Props are missing";
}

console.log(multiSearchOr(sentence, test1));
console.log(multiSearchOr(sentence, test2));
```

Comment: `indexOf` work case-sensitively. So, if the string contains `Hello` and you use `hello` in `searchWords`, your solution will not work. You can convert both strings to lowercase and then use `indexOf`.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but he never asked for this. Maybe he wants to return "Found" if the exact word was found in the sentence.

Comment: He did, when he used `i`-case-insensitive flag in the Regex.

Comment: Good catch ! I didn't check his code. I just wrote mine :)

Comment: Count Total Amount Of Specific Word In a String JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/a/65036248/4752258

Answer (score 0):

```
    if all(word in text for word in searchWords):
        print('found all')
    if any(word in text for word in searchWords):
        print('found at least one')
```

all() if you want that all the word in the list searchWords are in the text
any() if it's enough that one list word is in the text

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that will split the sentense you pass and check each word

```js
const matchAllEntries = (arr, target) => target.every(v => arr.includes(v));
const arr = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor'];
const strs = ['lorem blue dolor sky ipsum', 'sky loremdoloripsum blue', 'lorem dolor ipsum'];

strs.forEach(str => {
  // split on non alphabet and numbers (includes whitespace and puntuation)
  parts = str.split(/\W/); 
  console.log(matchAllEntries(arr, parts));
})
```