# Excluding special characters in regex match groups

Tags: javascript, regex, search

So I am working on something which has a search field to highlight matching strings/ characters from the data, to achieve this I am passing search query as regrex matching group. e.g.

`var pattern =
 new RegExp( "("+ matchThis+")" );`

And to eliminate special characters I tried this

`var pattern = 
new RegExp( "[^.#&]("+ matchThis+")" );`

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions how to achieve above mentioned functionality, little explanation would help a lot as I am new to RegExp.

Comment: What is `matchThis`? User-supplied or constant? ([mcve] please)

Comment: A variable to store user supplied values

Comment: Instead of trying to make the regex complex, just get all matching groups and filter out those with "special characters".

Comment: Please, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604794/searching-for-words-in-string

Comment: It highlights the matched text as soon as user enters a value. [ Think of it as find feature in your Chrome browser ]

Comment: _"Think of it as find feature in your Chrome browser"_ - Which finds exactly what I'm typing without any special handling of "special characters"

Comment: @user9804714: Can you give some sample text that should not get highlighted by your this statement? "And to eliminate special characters I tried this"

Comment: The question is extremely unclear. You should explain what you're trying to do, what `matchThis`'s contents is intended to be (you intend it to be raw text, not a regex), and how do you intend to use `pattern`, so someone may provide you a better solution. In the current state I can't see how your answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a work around for above problem.

It will work perfectly fine if I remove all the special characters from users input `searchThis` variable in this case. It can be done using RegExp as

`var pattern = 
new RegExp( "("+  searchThis.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/ig, "" ) +")" );`

Comment: Fixed, it was missing a ")"

Comment: Still makes no sense: `"a#b#c#".replace(/[^a-z0-9]/ig) === "aundefinedbundefinedcundefined"`

Comment: Yes, but it fits my requirement.

Comment: Why would it "fit the requirement" when your function finds `"aundefinedbundefinedcundefined"` when I'm looking for `abc`? O.o

Comment: */[^a-z0-9]/ig* removes everything from the string except chars from a-z and numbers from 0-9 case &quot;insensitive&quot;

Answer (score 0):

The `[^chars]` construction does not eliminate special characters, it just won't accept them. So I think your answer is more in line with what you need. Keep in mind though that your line of code is not valid - the `replace` function call is not closed with a paren. Also it's not given a second argument, which might default to empty string, but for clearer code I would add it. I think it should be:

```
new RegExp( "(" + searchThis.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/ig, "") + ")" );
```