# Count Total Amount Of Specific Word In a String JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, search, match, find-occurrences

I want to find out how many time a specific words occur in a String JavaScript, or we can say the total amount of matched/match word with the complete sentence string in JavaScript.

```
query = "fake";

var inputString = "fakefakefakegg fake 00f0 221 Hello wo fake misinfo fakeddfakefake , wo misinfo misinfo co wo fake , fake fake fake ";
```

expected result = 13 (there is 13 fake in the above sentence)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods to find the total number of occurrence match words in the string.

The first function allows you to give a query as input.
The second one uses the .match function of JavaScript.

Both introduced methods are resistant for any chars and independent of splitter and separator like " "  or ",".

**str1 is your query**

```
 str1 = "fake";
```

**str2 is  the whole string:**

```
 var inputString = "fakefakefakegg fake 00f0 221 Hello wo fake misinfo
 fakeddfakefake , wo  431,,asd misinfo misinfo co wo fake sosis bandari
 mikhori?, fake fake fake ";
```

Method 1 : use .indexOf or .search function of JavaScript (advantage you can give input)

```
function CountTotalAmountOfSpecificWordInaString(str1, str2)
{
    let next = 0;
    let findedword = 0;
        do {
            var n = str2.indexOf(str1, next);
            findedword = findedword +1;
            next = n + str1.length;
            }while (n>=0);
     console.log("total finded word :" , findedword - 1 );
     return findedword;
   }
```

Method 2 : use .match function of JavaScript:

```
/**
 * @return {number}
 *  you have to put fake as query manually in this solution!!! disadvantage
 */

function CountTotalAmountOfMachedWordInaString(str2) {
    let machedWord = 0;
    machedWord = str2.match(/fake/g).length; 
    console.log("total finded mached :" , machedWord);
    return machedWord;
}
```

call the functions (Inputs):

```
CountTotalAmountOfSpecificWordInaString("fake" , "fake fakefakegg fake 00f0 221 Hello wo fake rld fakefakefake , wo lklsak dalkkfakelasd co wo fake , fake fake fake" );
CountTotalAmountOfMachedWordInaString("sosis bandarie fake  khiyarshour sosis , droud bar fake to sosis3");


//Function 1 Output: total Fake = 13 , Function 2 Output: total Fake = 2
```

Comment: its possible to put the /var/g into a variable and str2.match( /var/g )