# Coded UI - C# - ExecuteScript - count does not return value correctly

Tags: javascript, c#, coded-ui-tests

I am observing a strange behavior using ExecuteScript in Coded UI. When two numbers are next to each other, count does not return the correct value. I'm not sure why it's happening. Here is the code snippet:

```
static long nowYearQA = 2030;
static long pastYearQA = 2029;

BrowserWindow window = new BrowserWindow();
window.WaitForControlEnabled();

long countCurrentYearQA = (long)window.ExecuteScript("count = 0; if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('" + nowYearQA.ToString().Trim() + "')  > -1){count = 1;} return count;");
long countPastYearQA = (long)window.ExecuteScript("count = 0; if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('" + pastYearQA.ToString().Trim() + "')  > -1){count = 1;} return count;");

MessageBox.Show(countCurrentYearQA + " " + countPastYearQA);
```

This is for a page validation where I'm checking whether certain number presents in the Inner Text of a page. If number presents, then it returns 1 and if number does not exist, then it returns 0. ExecutionScript code was adopted from the following discussion: [https://forums.asp.net/t/1945825.aspx?javascript+check+if+a+string+exists+on+page](https://forums.asp.net/t/1945825.aspx?javascript%20check%20if%20a%20string%20exists%20on%20page)

For the internal website where I tested it, count returns correct value if the difference between numbers is at least 2, but returns incorrectly when difference is greater than 2.

For a test I used https://www.google.com - for this site, difference between the number needs to be 3 to get the correct value. For example, if nowYearQA = 2030 and pastYearQA = 2029, or pastYearQA = 2028, then countCurrentYearQA gets 0 and countPastYearQA gets 1 - this is incorrect result.

When nowYearQA = 2030 and pastYearQA = 2027, then countCurrentYearQA gets 0 and countPastYearQA gets 0 - this is correct result.

Is there something I am overlooking here? Why is this difference? I understand from this [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2013/01/18/introducing-javascript-execution-on-internetexplorer-and-crossbrowser-in-coded-ui-test/) that "ExecuteScript API does not support Int, and only supports long" - this is the reason I've long cast the variables in the code snippet.

Comment: are you sure its consecutive integers, not the fact that when you had 200 and 2000 on the page, it would see 200 twice?

Comment: Hi  dlatikay, for consecutive value it shows incorrect result. In the internal site I'm testing, difference between two values must be 2 when correct result is displayed. For google.com site, difference must be 3.

Comment: when I do a full text search for "2030" in the markup of google.com, I get a match too because it occurs in some base64 string there. what are you trying to achieve with searching for occurrences of those number strings in body.innerHTML?

Comment: You are right, markup shows 2030, 2029 and 2028 in google.com page. That explains the behavior in google.com. Thank you. For the internal site that I'm testing, it's a news page. I am checking if current year or the past year exists on the news page. Since it was showing incorrect result, I hard coded year values to test and found that consecutive values does not show the correct result. Now that you've pointed out the markup checking, I will search that page carefully. Is there a better way to validate if a page contains current or past year or current year - 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that you search the entire markup source for four-digit numeric strings, which are likely to occur somewhere.

I suggest three improvements:

1. Search in innerText, not in innerHTML. In this way numbers that are part of invisible tags like scripts, are excluded
2. Target the tag(s) that contain the year numbers specifically. Inspect the markup to find the appropriate criteria for a selector, for example an id value:

   `document.getElementByID('yearspan').innerText`
3. search for whole words only, not with the `indexOf` function. Find an example of how that can be done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2232947/1132334

Comment: Thank you dlatikay for the quick feedback. I will update the code accordingly.