# C# - How to Populate a List from ExecuteScript in Coded UI

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Continuation from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765069/coded-ui-c-sharp-time-itemprop-tag-how-to-validate-year-exists) where jQuery snippet works in a browser, but when I try to get the return value of the script into a list in C#, it looks object is null. I am trying to get years in listYears like: 2018, 2017, 2015, 2012 from an internal web page. Running jQuery on the browser works as it pulls the years correctly, but when I try to use C# to get years returned from jQuery into a list, it looks not populating, or I'm not using the correct C# construct. What mistake I'm making in C# code?

```
List<string> listYears = new List<string>();

listYears = (List<string>)window.ExecuteScript(@"$(document).ready(function(){
 var scr = document.createElement('script');
 scr.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js';
 document.body.appendChild(scr);

 var years = []
 var thisYear = 0;

 $('time').each(function(){
   thisYear = parseInt($(this).attr('datetime').split('-')[0]);
        years.push(thisYear);
 });

    return years.toString();
});");

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("listYears: " + listYears[0]);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
```

or,

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("listYears: " + listYears);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
```

Comment: Hi Rufus, yes, I have tried to return years, like: return years - in the JavaScript, still looks to be null is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, corrected the issue, listYears now showing all the years from executed jQuery script.

```
var listYears = window.ExecuteScript(@"

                    $=jQuery;
                    var years = [];
                    var thisYear = 0;

                    $('time').each(function(){
                        thisYear = parseInt($(this).attr('datetime').split('-')[0]);
                    // do something with thisYear...
                        years.push(thisYear);
                    });
                    // Write all years to console window.
                    return years.toString();
                    ");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("listYears: " + listYears);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
```