# How to make RegExp match whole word

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex, ajax

Can the second parameter of a RegExp be to match the whole word that is given in the first parameter?

```
new RegExp(words, `g`)
```

I have tried everything but it does not work. Does someone know how to make this happen?

**UPDATE:**

I have a list of words that I want to match in a paragraph.
I use .replace(/\b(dog|cat|pet)/gi, replaceWords) to match exactly the words in the first parameter.

The problem is is that I have more then 300 words. How can I make the RegExp match the whole word in the second parameter?

Comment: Try word boundary `\b word \b`

Comment: what is `words`?

Comment: The second parameter contains the flags. What do you mean by "match the whole word" ? Can you add some examples ?

Comment: See [whole word match in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232934/whole-word-match-in-javascript).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. This fixed the problem