# Add Active Navigation Class Based On Url for similar url

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, navigation

I am trying to add active class in navigation.
I used this article.
[Add Active Navigation Class Based on URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url)

```
$(function(){
    var current = location.pathname;
    $('#nav li a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // if the current path is like this link, make it active
        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    })
})
```

It worked well.
But my issue is in this case.

```
/blog, /blogAds
```

If url is `/blog,` active class added to both nav items.
Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if( new RegExp(location.pathname + "$").test( $this.attr('href') ) ) {
    $this.addClass('active');
}
```

Tested with:

```
new RegExp('\/blog$').test('/blogAds'); // returns false
new RegExp('\/blog$').test('/blog'); // returns true
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232934/whole-word-match-in-javascript)