# Check if a string contains a strict substring

Tags: javascript

I have the next situation:
I want to check if in `const str = "hello world"` is the word `world`, not `wor`, not `worl`, but strict `world`. I know that exists `includes()` method, but it is not working as i described.
How to solve the question?

Comment: `"hello world".includes("hello")` is `true` while `"hell world".includes("hello")` is `false`.

Comment: @VLAZ maybe OP also mean to "hello worldo" which includes return true.

Comment: @VLAZ, why `str.includes("wor");` is true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [whole word match in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232934/whole-word-match-in-javascript)

Comment: @Asking because the substring exists. Your question wasn't at all clear about this. The situation you described in the question didn't suffer the problem you described.

Comment: @MoshFeu `"hello worldo".includes("hello")` is still *correctly* `true`, and `"hell worldo".includes("hello")` is *correctly* `false`.

Comment: Yes but `"helloooo worldo".includes("hello")` is true

Answer (score -1):

```js
const str = "hello world"
const sub1 = "world"
const sub2 = "wor"

let strictSub = (a, b) => a.split(' ').includes(b)

console.log(strictSub(str, sub1))
console.log(strictSub(str, sub2))
```

This would work

Answer (score -3):

Using Regex :

```js
const str1 = "hello world"
const str2 = "helloooo world"

const regex = /\bhello\b/

regex.test(str1) // true
regex.test(str2) // false
```

Comment: How is this different to `str.includes("hello")`?

Comment: @VLAZ, why str.includes("wor"); is true?

Comment: @VLAZ because "helloooo".includes("hello") is true. I agree that my regex is not totally exact. It need to be updated to match exactly "hello" not "helloo"

Comment: @Alexandre `/hello/.test("helloooo")` is similarly `true`.

Comment: yes i agree, we need a better regex to match exactly hello

Comment: do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: [You can use word boundries `\b`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232934/how-can-i-match-a-whole-word-in-javascript)

Comment: I have update my answer, thanks for your help
/\bhello\b/.test('hello world') // true
/\bhello\b/.test('helloooo world') // false